# What kind of Ruby on Rails model association for a "simple" lookup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have the following scenario I am trying to configure in a Ruby on Rails app (warning: I'm a beginner here)...

I have SupportType model that defines different levels of customer support options (Silver, Gold etc) with details about what that support type covers (24/7, business day only etc).

I have another model, Client that contains all of the basic customer information data.

I need to associate a Client to a SupportType (Client Jones has Gold-level support) but can't understand the "proper" way to set up this relationship. Neither "has_many" or "has_one" seems to apply in this case.

How do I set this up with the goal of being able to display all client details and the support parameters in one view?

TIA!

Comment: Use a many to many association to setup the following that way a client could have silver, gold , etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :support_type
end

class SupportType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
end
```

This way you can access client's support type with `a_client.support_type` and see all the clients having gold support type with `gold_support.clients`

You can't use has_one in the Client model because in that case [Rails aspects to find a client_id in the support_types DB table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association) and it's not the case if I understood well since many clients can have the same SupportType.

PS: Remember to add a support_type_id column to your clients DB table

Comment: Perfect answer and easy to follow. Thank you.

Comment: if you have a foreign key named something other than support_type_id, you can write `:belongs_to :support_type, :foreign_key => "foreign_key_id"`